# how to get action name from url in variable, not from routedata

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have url in variable (so I can't use RouteData.Values["action"]):

```
string url = "/aaaa/bbb?c=5";
```

how can I get action name from this url in variable??

Answer (score 1):

if you are using realtive url, prepend `application path` using provide function as `HttpRequest` require complete path

```
string url = GetApplicationPath(HttpContext.Request) + "/aaaa/bbb?c=5"; 
var request = new HttpRequest(null,  url, "");
var response = new HttpResponse(new StringWriter());
var httpContext = new HttpContext(request, response);
var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext));
var values = routeData.Values;

var controller = values["controller"]; //aaaa
var action = values["action"]; //bbb
```

Value of controller and action will depend upon, route settings in the `Global.asax`, if you have following setting

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Output will be

```
var controller = values["controller"]; //aaaa
var action = values["action"]; //bbb
```

However you have setting as

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{action}/{controller}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Output will be

```
var controller = values["controller"]; //bbb
var action = values["action"]; //aaaa
```

Add a utility function function

```
private string GetApplicationPath(HttpRequestBase request)
{
    var path = request.Url.Scheme + "://" + request.Url.Host;
    if (request.ApplicationPath != @"/")
    {
        path += request.ApplicationPath;
    }
    if (!path.EndsWith(@"/"))
    {
        path += "/";
    }
    return path;
}
```